# VBA code: IF X = True, THEN - do several things

Tags: excel, vba

Very new to VBA but I'm trying to write the code to make certain worksheets in an Excel spreadsheet Very Hidden to any user who doesn't have a password.  I can get it to work for a single worksheet ("Summary") with this code:

```
Sub hide_worksheet(X As Boolean)
If X = True Then
Sheets("Summary").Visible = xlVeryHidden
Else
Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
End If
End Sub
```

What I need to do for the same "X = True" condition is repeat this exact logic for 4 other worksheets.

Appreciate any advice (hopefully not too complicated!).

Able to finds lots of examples on nested IF's but I need multiple "THEN's".

Comment: You just put "multiple thens" each on their own line between the `If` line and the `Else` or `End If` line. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-ifthenelse-statements

Answer (score 1):

Just insert more lines to hide for each sheet ?

```
Sub hide_worksheet(X As Boolean)
    If X = True Then
        Sheets("Summary").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        Sheets("Details").Visible = xlVeryHidden
        ...
    Else
        Sheets("Summary").Visible = True
        Sheets("Details").Visible = True
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get past 3 sheets, it is neater/tidier and more efficient to use an array to get the result you require.

Also, you don't strictly speaking need to use the `If` statement at all if you are happy converting a Boolean value into a XlSheetVisibility equivalent..

You can use:

```
Sub hide_worksheet(X As Boolean)

    arrSheets = Array("Summary", "Detail", "Sheet3", "Sheet4")
    
    For Each sh In Sheets(arrSheets)
        sh.Visible = (-3 * X) - 1
    Next

End Sub
```

In case you're wondering, `(-3 * X) - 1` converts the `X` value of

`True (-1)`/`False (0)` to

`xlVeryHidden (2)`/`True (-1)` respectively.